# Send raw image through JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm building an Android app which uses a C++ core. I want to save images from Java through the core and JNI. I can get a byte array with the image data, but can't find a good way to send this through JNI. The jbyteArray I get on the JNI side isn't easily read with null bytes in the array.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 /*quality*/, stream);
byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
```

Any tips on how I do this?

Comment: I find it unclear exactly what you're asking. Please add the relevant native code and explain more clearly what the problem is.

Comment: did you mean jni by library of using c++ through java? did you mean opencv?

Comment: Send it where? How can you possibly have a problem sending a byte array anywhere?

Comment: I want to get raw image data (byte[] in java) to JNI. I need to send it to my c++ core which saves the file on the server. When I pass a byte[] to JNI i get a jbyteArray, which I don't know how to convert to a std::string or similar to present the data. Since it contains null bytes the methods I've found don't work.